# Why is wheel oil provided with a Montolit tile cutter?

Tags: tile, cutting

I am thinking to buy a Montolit tile cutter for a diy project, thinking that it will be useful in the future too. According to [this site](https://www.tiletools.com/product/montolit-masterpiuma-p3/) The P3 version introduces an oil bottle to lubricate the cutting wheel.

I do not have any experience with tile cutters. Does this mean that other tile cutters do not necessarily use oil on the wheel? What if they stop producing this replacement bottles with oil, or change its size etc., can I still use the cutter without oil?

Comment: All the tile and brick saws I have ever seen on construction sites use water not oil. Water keeps the blade cool, reduces dust to almost none, and makes for easier cleanup. When oil gets thrown all over the place by the blade, it sounds like a real mess.

Comment: Maybe they are just trying to sell you replacement oils for a lifetime. I think I will go for a Sigma.

Answer (score 1):

This particular cutter is a score & snap tool, not a saw. The oil is just to lubricate the scoring wheel bearing/bushing, and not the cut itself. It's a very different animal from a wet saw, which uses a flood of water.

Most saws probably don't come with oil because either 1) they use sealed bearings in the scoring wheels, or 2) they don't expect that you'll put enough mileage on the saw to wear through the grease they apply at assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Oil prevents the glass from knitting back together or that is what a friend that worked in a glass shop told me. Also to make the score and snap quickly aids in a clean snap. Any light oil will work I have used motor oil and cooking oil I did not see much difference if any.